# Como rotacionar e mover o canvas com o keydown?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, javascript-eventos

Fala galera! Sou iniciante em JS e HTML. Tem muita coisa que entendo o raciocinio mas me atrapalho na hora de codificar. Vou tentar explicar o que estou tentando fazer. Estou desenhando um triangulo (chamado Jack), com um pequeno nariz vermelho (mini triangulo) e um olho (circulo), ate ai de boa.
Meu objetivo eh mover o Jack pra direcoes de acordo com as setas do teclado, com o nariz sempre apontando pra direcao que ele esta movendo. Ah, e qdo apertar o botao reset, ele volta pra posicao inicial, que eh o centro do canvas.

Tentei desenhar mais ou menos o comando, mas nao funciona. Abaixo vou mostrar meu HTML e meu JS. O que estou errando no JS? Nao entendi como faco pra rotacionar o jack, eu teria que rotacionar dentro do switch de cada tecla?

Valeu!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Canvas</title>
   <script src="a5.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
</head>

<body onload="setUp()">
     <h1>The Adventure of Jack the Triangle</h1>
     <canvas id="myCanvas" height="500" width="500" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>

<br>
<button type="button" id="resetbtt" name="button">Reset</button>

</body>
```

JS:

```
let canvas;
let ctx;
let dx = 10;
let dy = 10;
let x = 250;
let y = 250;


function setUp(){
     canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     drawJack();
}

function drawJack(){

     ctx.save();
     ctx.translate(x,y)
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
     ctx.lineTo(-50, 50);
     ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
     ctx.closePath();
     ctx.stroke();
     ctx.restore();

 //NARIZ
     ctx.save();
     ctx.fillStyle = "red";
     ctx.translate(x,y)
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
     ctx.lineTo(-10, 10);
     ctx.lineTo(10, 10);
     ctx.closePath();
     ctx.stroke();
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.restore();

 //OLHO
     ctx.save();
     ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
     ctx.translate(x,y)
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(0, 30, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.restore();
}


let deltaX = 0;   
let deltaY = 0;

window.addEventListener("keydown", moveJack);

function moveJack(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            x -= dx;
            break;
        case 38:
            y -= dy;
            break;
        case 39:
            x += dx;
            break;
        case 40:
            y += dy;
            break;
     }
     e.preventDefault();
 }
```

Comment: Utilize `ctx.translate(largura do elemento / 2, altura do elemento / 2);`. Logo depois basta calcular o ângulo e adicionar o resultado em `ctx.rotate( 45 * PI / 180 );` depois basta utilizar o `translate` (com número negativos agora) e depois é só redesenhar o canvas.

Comment: Vou tentar aqui. E sobre mover o triângulo usando as teclas? Criei uma função mas não funciona, não sei o que está faltando, no console não tem erros

Comment: Toda alteração que você fizer no `ctx`, é necessário redesenhar o canvas.